# How to read a big(>300 MB) image or video file via javascript file api, store it locally, retrieve it and display?

Tags: javascript, blob, indexeddb, fileapi, offlineapps

I have to read a big file which user uploads using javascript's file api. Since this file is huge, reading it as is crashes the browser. So, I slice the file and it forms an array of blobs (Can slice method create array of any other type?).

JS Code:

```
var chunkSize = 100000; 
var currentStart = 0;
var currentEnd = Math.min(currentStart+chunkSize, file.size);
while(currentEnd != file.size){
        var blobPart = file.slice(currentStart, currentEnd);
        blobs.push(blobPart);
        currentStart = currentEnd+1;
        currentEnd =  Math.min(currentStart+chunkSize, file.size);
}
```

After this I have an array of blobs known as 'blobs'. How do I store this array(I am using localforage (indexeddb)). Currently I am storing the blobs array as it is.

JS Code:

```
    localforage.setItem(file.name,blobs,function(){
        localforage.getItem(file.name, function(err, value){
            var fullRetrievedBlobArray = [];
            var x = value;

        });     
    });
```

Can converting it to something else help? Or should I read the blobs in 'blobs' array and convert them to one big array? (If yes, how do I do that?).

After retrieving x will contain the array of blobs which I had store. **Now How do I merge this blob to get the original file as a big data url?**

[image: Snapshot of the retrieved 'blobs' array]

If I upload a video in similar way? How can I merge the blob arrays to form a data url to add to attribute tag of html 5 video tag?
Also, Can someone provide a little bit of high-level explanation of how localforage stores this array. Does it directly set it?

Answer (score 3):

The blob constructor takes a mixed array of buffers, strings and other blobs:

```
var hugeBlob = new Blob(blobs, {type: "video/mp4"});
document.getElementById("video").src = URL.createObjectURL(hugeBlob);
```

Comment: Thanks, I came across this bit of information, but, as you'll see my problems are big files. If I merge the small blobs to form a big blob. I will have a hard time to read it again. For instance, I have a blob array of size ~3500 each of 10 mb (comes around 300 mb total). When I try to read this huge blob it will crash the browser. Any way to read Big blobs so that they do not crash the browser?

Comment: @AkshayShinde you wouldn't read a large file at once in any environment. I'd say even 10mb chunks are unnecessarily large. You have already solved your problem of reading large files: do it in chunks.  I was answering your question of how to merge the blob slices back to a single blob.